# How do I set java version for a particular sonarlint scan?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I have installed SonarLint eclipse plugin. I would like to see only those issues which are compatible with Java 1.7. Is there an way to set a particular version for running sonar scan? I checked the options and couldn't find anything.

Just to clarify, I don't want to know how to set java version for Sonar itself. I would like to set java versions for individual scans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your environment, this may not be politically feasible, but I'll answer ignoring politics:

First, you need to set up a rule profile on your SonarQube server that's limited to just the rules you want to see - the Java 7 rules and assign it to your project so only those rules are used in analysis.

Now [connect](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html#Connected) your project in Eclipse to the project on your SonarQube server.

Voila! Only those Java 7 rules are applied in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks! But there is no option within the Sonarlint plugin I guess.